# How to separate the number and special character in equation using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have one question on javascript, the user type the maths equation as input. Based on equation how to separate the characters in multiplication, addition,and power value?For Example: user type the maths equation in 10x2+5y+65=0 based on equation I want to 10*x^2+5*y+65=0 suppose user type any equation.How to separate the addition,subtraction,multiplication,division and power values are shown in output using javascript? so please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you would like to do with the equation? Maybe there's a better way to do it?

Comment: @JayGhosh i want type any maths equation for example:100x+65y2-20=0 that eqaution user type in input but output i want to separate the 100*x+65*y^2-20=0 in  that based modal i want how its separate?

Comment: You could use the `replace` method of JS to manually replace all the characters you want removed with a blank string `""`

Comment: Basically, before any variable you need multiplication sign and after variable power, if number exists after variable. Right?

Comment: @ADarnal YA its Right

Comment: @ADarnal  Any example code please help me.

Comment: @pram just a moment

Comment: @ADarnal kk thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. (Needs a little refining)

```
function convert(q){
    q = q.replace(/([0-9]+)([a-zA-Z])/g,"$1*$2");
    return q.replace(/([a-zA-Z])([0-9]+)/g,"$1^$2");
}

var q = "10x2+5y+65=0";

console.log(convert(q));
```

Comment: It should. Try it with a few and let me know

Comment: I have modified the answer to make it more optimised

Comment: before your edited modal are working but its suitable for all equation are not  and after modified answer are not working.

Comment: I just optimised it. Didn't change the logic. The function `convert` does 2 things. __Firstly__ it adds a `*` between any number and variable. And __secondly__ it adds a `^` between any variable and number. That's exactly what you wanted, right?

Comment: ya its Right but not only *^ value convert all +-*/^ value

Comment: I didn't get you. Please explain with an example. `10x2+5y+65=0` should be `10*x^2+5*y+65=0`, right? That is exactly what's happening

Comment: user type:10x2+5y-20=0;

Comment: Then he/she will get `10*x^2+5*y-20=0`.